# Background color not changing when it's hovered CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Hi guys I am creating a custom mouse-like thing, I want its colour to be white when it hovers links
IDK what's wrong with my code, it's not working properly when select parent element it works fine but when I use child element it's not working help me out, I got stuck with this code for like 4 hours I need help

Here's my code

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
const cursor2 = document.querySelector('.cursor2');
document.addEventListener('mousemove',(e) =>{
  cursor.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  cursor.style.top =  e.pageY + 'px';
  cursor2.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  cursor2.style.top =  e.pageY + 'px';
} )
```

```css
*{
    cursor: none;
}
body{
    background-color: black;

}
.cursor{
    position: fixed;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: .12s;
  }
  
  .cursor2{
    position: fixed;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #c6c6c6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: .06s;
  }
  ul li a:hover ~ .cursor {
 background-color: white;
  }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
           </ul>
    </div>



    <div class="cursor"></div>
    <div class="cursor2"></div>
```

I just pasted whatever code I coded, I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this, We can use Javascript instead of relying on CSS for this

HTML

```
<a onmouseenter="onHover()"  onmouseleave="notHover()" href="#">Text<a>

<div class="cursor"></div>
<div class="cursor2"></div>
```

JS part

```
const cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
const cursor2 = document.querySelector('.cursor2');

document.addEventListener('mousemove',(e) =>{
  cursor.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  cursor.style.top =  e.pageY + 'px';
  cursor2.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  cursor2.style.top =  e.pageY + 'px';
} )


function onHover(){
  cursor.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  cursor.style.height = "70px";
  cursor.style.width = "70px";
  cursor2.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  console.log("hello")
}

function notHover(){
  cursor.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  cursor.style.height = "50px";
  cursor.style.width = "50px";
  cursor2.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

CSS

```
*{
    cursor: none;
}
body{
    background-color: black;

}
.cursor{
    position: fixed;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: .12s;
  }
  
  .cursor2{
    position: fixed;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #c6c6c6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: .06s;
  }
  
  .nav:hover ~ .cursor {
    background-color: white;
  }
```

Thanks to the one who helped with this problem I found an alternative way to do this and want to share this with everyone so if anyone is stuck with this. Thank you once again to who helped me

Answer (score 2):

```CSS
ul li a:hover ~ .cursor
```

This CSS selector applies for every element having the class `cursor` that is preceded by an `a` element that is hovered.

But in the HTML you provided, the `div` having the `cursor` class is preceded by a `div` having the `nav` class.

Using CSS, the only solution I can think of is to use this selector :

```CSS
.nav:hover ~ .cursor
```

You can add `width: min-content;` to all `li` elements to avoid the white background to spread too far.

Note that if the `div.cursor` is placed immediately after the `div.nav` in your complete HTML, you should use `+` instead of `~`.

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
const cursor2 = document.querySelector('.cursor2');
document.addEventListener('mousemove',(e) =>{
  cursor.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  cursor.style.top =  e.pageY + 'px';
  cursor2.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  cursor2.style.top =  e.pageY + 'px';
} )
```

```css
*{
    cursor: none;
}
body{
    background-color: black;

}
.cursor{
    position: fixed;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: .12s;
  }
  
  .cursor2{
    position: fixed;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #c6c6c6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: .06s;
  }
  
  .nav:hover ~ .cursor {
    background-color: white;
  }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
           </ul>
    </div>



    <div class="cursor"></div>
    <div class="cursor2"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much it helped me a lot, now I got an idea why it didn't and thanks again to speed your valuable time for answering my question

Comment: It's not working yet because of my file structure so, I think I need to use any 3rd party library instead of relying on plain native code

Answer (score 2):

There are two answers to this question:

1- when you can use `~`, that `a` and `<div class="cursor"></div>` in same parent.

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
const cursor2 = document.querySelector('.cursor2');
document.addEventListener('mousemove',(e) =>{
  cursor.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  cursor.style.top =  e.pageY + 'px';
  cursor2.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  cursor2.style.top =  e.pageY + 'px';
} )
```

```css
 *{
    cursor: none;
}
body{
    background-color: black;

}
.cursor{
    position: fixed;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: .12s;
  }
  
  .cursor2{
    position: fixed;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #c6c6c6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: .06s;
  }
 .nav a:hover ~ .cursor {
 background-color: white;
  }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>
            <a href="#">Hello</a>
            <div class="cursor"></div>
            <div class="cursor2"></div>
             </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

**2- if you could not change structure of html**, you can hover on `ul`:

```CSS
.nav:hover ~ .cursor {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
const cursor2 = document.querySelector('.cursor2');
document.addEventListener('mousemove',(e) =>{
  cursor.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  cursor.style.top =  e.pageY + 'px';
  cursor2.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  cursor2.style.top =  e.pageY + 'px';
} )
```

```css
 *{
    cursor: none;
}
body{
    background-color: black;

}
.cursor{
    position: fixed;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: .12s;
  }
  
  .cursor2{
    position: fixed;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #c6c6c6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: .06s;
  }
 .nav:hover ~ .cursor {
 background-color: white;
  }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>
            <a href="#">Hello</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>

<div class="cursor"></div>
<div class="cursor2"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for spending your valuable time answering my question, it helped me a lot